# INNER JOIN causes query executes very long

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have quite big table with millions of records. The query below executes in just 0.2s, which is fine.

```
SELECT ch1.*
FROM citizens_history ch1
WHERE ch1.update_id_to = ( 
    SELECT MAX( ch2.update_id_to ) 
    FROM citizens_history ch2
    WHERE ch2.id = ch1.id
)
ORDER BY ch1.experience DESC
LIMIT 100
```

However, when I tried to add INNER JOIN, like this

```
SELECT ch1.*, upd.*
FROM citizens_history ch1
INNER JOIN updates upd ON upd.id = ch1.update_id_to
WHERE ch1.update_id_to = ( 
    SELECT MAX( ch2.update_id_to ) 
    FROM citizens_history ch2
    WHERE ch2.id = ch1.id
)
ORDER BY ch1.experience DESC
LIMIT 100
```

It takes forever to execute. In first situation I think MySQL is doing this:

1. Orders by experience using index
2. Applies WHERE
3. Finishes when there is 100 records found

In second situation, I assume this happens:

1. Orders by experience using index
2. Joins for every single record out of the millions of rows <-- slow
3. Applies WHERE
4. Finishes when there is 100 records found

Do you have any advices how can I optimize this?

**Edit**: EXPLAIN for fast and slow query:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ch1   | index | NULL          | experience | 3       | NULL         |  100 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ch2   | ref   | id            | id         | 3       | db.ch1.id    |    1 | Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------+------+-------------+

+----+--------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys                       | key      | key_len | ref          | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | upd   | index | PRIMARY                             | datetime | 5       | NULL         |  389 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ch1   | ref   | PRIMARY,update_id_to,update_id_to_2 | PRIMARY  | 4       | db.upd.id    |  112 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ch2   | ref   | id                                  | id       | 3       | db.ch1.id    |    1 | Using index                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you do the first query in a subquery and then do the join afterwards?

Comment: I would need to do a lot of changes in code of my application. Would it be possible without putting main query into subquery?

Comment: Well stop assuming, prefix the query with Explain and see what the query plan is. I'd expect the biggest hit to be the order by and the aggregate myself. Number of possibilities, but without an execution plan I can't even guess properly

Comment: Why would Gordon's suggestion have any impact on the application? FWIW, I suspect the hit IS the correlated subquery! I think the 0.2 secs is a cached result!

Comment: Just as @GordonLinoff mentioned above try the first query in a sub query and join after that.Then select the same result from the whole query.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the first query as follows, and then modify as required...

```
SELECT ch1.*
  FROM citizens_history ch1
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id
            , MAX(update_id_to) max_update_id_to 
         FROM citizens_history 
        GROUP 
           BY id
     ) ch2
    ON ch2.id = ch1.id
   AND ch2.max_update_id_to = ch1.update_id_to
 ORDER 
    BY ch1.experience DESC
 LIMIT 100
```

If you're still struggling (performancewise), provide an EXPLAIN for the above together with proper DDLS of all relevant tables.

Answer (score 0):

Performing the first stage as a JOIN to a sub query, and then joining on the updates table:-

```
SELECT ch1.*, upd.*
FROM citizens_history ch1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT id, MAX( update_id_to ) AS max_update_id_to
    FROM citizens_history 
    GROUP BY id
) ch2 ON ch1.id = ch2.id AND ch1.update_id_to = ch2.max_update_id_to
INNER JOIN updates upd ON upd.id = ch1.update_id_to
ORDER BY ch1.experience DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
  SELECT ch1.*
  FROM citizens_history ch1
  LEFT JOIN citizens_history ch2
    ON ch2.id = ch1.id
    AND ch1.max_update_id_to > ch2.update_id_to
  WHERE ch1.max_update_id_to is null 
  ORDER BY ch1.experience DESC
  LIMIT 100
```